# MoviePy - Set audio length to clip

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

Can anyone help me to trim the audio file to match the video length?
At the moment the video finishes at 8 seconds but it plays for 2min+

```
clip = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
clip_duration = clip.duration

audioclip = AudioFileClip("huru.wav")
new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])
clip.audio = new_audioclip


txt_clip = TextClip("Some Text",fontsize=70,color='black')
txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos("bottom","center").set_duration(clip_duration)

video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip])

video.write_videofile("video2.mp4")
```

Comment: Use `new_audioclip = new_audioclip.subclip(0, clip.duration)`

Comment: Unfortunately does not work

Comment: Did you try `new_audioclip = new_audioclip.subclip(0, clip_duration)`? Maybe the variable works better than the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
audioclip = AudioFileClip("huru.wav")
new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])
clip.audio = new_audioclip
```

try

```
audioclip = AudioFileClip("huru.wav").set_duration(clip_duration)
new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])
clip = clip.set_audio(new_audioclip)
```

you can use `set_start()` too

Comment: With that code I get a value error of "requires_duration
    raise ValueError("Attribute 'duration' not set")"

Comment: Are you sure you have there `.set_duration(clip_duration)` ? On which clip it's not set? Can you set it?

Comment: ah perfect! Just had to also add it to output video: video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip]).set_duration(clip_duration)